# Port problem? Mindstorms EV3 brick doesn't detect sensor blocks

Tags: ev3, mac

I've just bought a second hand Mindstorms EV3 home edition set but the ports aren't detecting any of the sensors just the motors.
When checking the ports on the EV3 brick it says "none". I've updated the firmware and I'm running the Mindstorms home edition software for Mac (Mac mini with OS Capitan).

Answer (score 5):

Welcome Violetta. The EV3 Brick has a total of 8 ports - 4 output ports on one side labeled A-D, used for driving motors, and 4 input ports on the other side of the brick labeled 1-4, used for getting information from sensors.

[image]

(Image sourced from [this page](https://shaneabell.wixsite.com/furnacechallenge/basics?lightbox=dataItem-jn09lu5f1))

Make sure you have plugged your sensors into the correct port, as plugging them into ports A-D will not allow the Brick to detect them.

Comment: Can you plug motors into 1-4? I haven't tried that yet, but if the OP says that only motors are being detected and none of the sensors are, then it sounds like ALL of her sensors are in 1-4 or A-D and it sounds like her motors are like that too, which tells me that one of the groupings of ports could be defective.